# replace the word using powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a text file for setting up environment variables. I need to change the value for 'config' variable. below is the file content

env.mode: on
**config: env**
server: 2
db : mssql
.........
.........

env value can be anything. it should be replaced to prod. (config: prod). I know we can replace the word using powershell get-content. since word is not static, need to set the value using Powershell. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$file = 'c:\myconfig.config'
$configValue = 'prod'
(Get-Content $file) -replace '^config:.*', "config: $configValue" | Set-Content $file
```